# Quectel chip QIMODE change with '+++' & 'ATO'

Tags: mobile, arduino, gsm, at-command, arduino-uno

I am trying to implement my library to send data over tcp connection.

In official documentation from Quectel they let you select `AT+QIMODE=1` also called Transparent mode where all data sent from UART is sent over tcp connection.

I am trying to check connection status before sending data so would want to change to command mode and use AT+QISTAT. I tried sending '+++' to chip but it's sending '+++' to my server, so it's not working. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[Link to official documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Quectel_M10_AT_commands.pdf), please refer to page 162 section 7.2.21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you ensured you have the correct time delay before and after the `+++` sequence?

The documentation at section 2.2.11 (page 22) states that there must be a quiet period of 0.5 seconds before and after the `+++` for it to be recognised.

> To prevent the "+++" escape sequence from being misinterpreted as data, it should comply to following sequence:
>
> 1. No characters entered for T1 time (0.5 seconds).
> 2. "+++" characters entered with no characters in between. For CSD call or PPP online mode, the interval between two "+" MUST be less than 1 second and for a transparent TCPIP connection, the interval MUST be less than 20 ms.
> 3. No characters entered for T1 time (0.5 seconds).
> 4. Switch to command mode, otherwise go to step 1.

If you still don't have any success please post some example code.

Comment: Interesting, I missed it. I will try and let you know.